# 2D radial high speed collision detection

Tags: geometry, vectors

Let's say we have 2 circles P and Q with radius of R. P has an initial position PxZero,PyZero and Q has an initial position QxZero,QyZero. They have constant velocities Pvx,Pvy and Qvx,Qvy. The task is to create an equation that can predict T where T is time of collision.
What I have tried to do :

Formula of x and y of any points with respect to time
$x_{t} = t\cdot v_{x} + x_{0}$
$y_{t} = t\cdot v_{y} + x_{0}$

Formula of distance between two particles P and Q at time t
$\sqrt{\left ( Px_{t}-Qx_{t} \right )^{2} + \left ( Py_{t}-Qy_{t} \right )^{2}}$

Substituting the formula of Px, Qx, Py and Qy to get the formula for distance between P and Q. A formula that includes the time variable
$\sqrt{\left ( t\cdot Pv_{x} + Px_{0} - t\cdot Qv_{x} - Qx_{0} \right )^{2} + \left ( t\cdot Pv_{y} + Py_{0} - t\cdot Qv_{y} - Qy_{0} \right )^{2}}$

Simplification
$t\cdot Pv_{x} - t\cdot Qv_{x} = t\cdot \left ( Pv_{x} - Qv_{x} \right )$
$t\cdot Pv_{y} - t\cdot Qv_{y} = t\cdot \left ( Pv_{y} - Qv_{y} \right )$
$\sqrt{\left ( t\cdot \left ( Pv_{x}-Qv_{x} \right ) + Px_{0} - Qx_{0} \right )^{2} + \left ( t\cdot \left ( Pv_{y}-Qv_{y} \right ) + Py_{0} - Qy_{0} \right )^{2}}$

Thinking about these variables as constants I thought of reducing the number of variable by combining them :
$Pv_{x}-Qv_{x} = \Delta V_{x}$
$Pv_{y}-Qv_{y} = \Delta V_{y}$
$Px_{0}-Qx_{0} = \Delta x_{0}$
$Py_{0}-Qy_{0} = \Delta y_{0}$
$\sqrt{\left ( t\cdot \Delta V_{x} + \Delta x_{0} \right )^{2} + \left ( t\cdot \Delta V_{y} + \Delta y_{0} \right )^{2}}$

If the two particles were to collide the distance between them would be equal to 2R
$4R^{2} = \left ( t\cdot \Delta V_{x} + \Delta x_{0} \right )^{2} + \left ( t\cdot \Delta V_{y} + \Delta y_{0} \right )^{2}$

$= t^{2}\cdot \Delta V_{x}^{2} + (\Delta x_{0})^{2} + 2t\cdot \Delta V_{x} \cdot \Delta x_{0} + t^{2}\cdot \Delta V_{y}^{2} + (\Delta y_{0})^{2} + 2t\cdot \Delta V_{y} \cdot \Delta y_{0}$

$4R^{2} = t^{2}\cdot (\Delta V_{x}^{2} + \Delta V_{y}^{2}) + 2t\cdot (\Delta V_{x} \cdot \Delta x_{0} + \Delta V_{y} \cdot \Delta y_{0})+ (\Delta x_{0})^{2} +(\Delta y_{0})^{2}$

$T = \frac{-2 \pm \sqrt{4-4\cdot \left [ \frac{(\Delta x_{0})^{2} + (\Delta y_{0})^{2} - 4R^{2})}{((\Delta V_{x})^{2} - (\Delta V_{y})^{2})\cdot (\Delta V_{x}\cdot \Delta x_{0} + \Delta V_{y}\cdot \Delta y_{0})} \right ]}}{2}$

Now finally I get a quadratic equation. But the equation is wrong. When I tested the equation with made up values it completely failed. What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Your expression for $T$ is wrong. It looks like you misapplied the formula for the solution of a quadratic equation.

Comment: Oh yes... I see it now... damn.. Thanx man appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in the last step.
The final equation for T is as follows

$t = \frac{\left [ \left ( 2\cdot \left ( \Delta V_{x}\cdot \Delta x_{0} + \Delta V_{y}\cdot \Delta y_{0} \right ) \right ) \mp \sqrt{\left ( 2\cdot \left ( \Delta V_{x}\cdot \Delta x_{0} + \Delta V_{y}\cdot \Delta y_{0} \right ) \right )^{2} - 4 \cdot \left ( \Delta V_{x}^{2} + \Delta V_{y}^{2}a = \Delta V_{x}^{2} + \Delta V_{y}^{2} \right )\cdot \left ( \left ( \Delta x_{0} \right )^{2} + \left ( \Delta y_{0} \right )^{2} - 4R^{2} \right )} \right ]}{\left [ 2\cdot \left ( \Delta V_{x}^{2} + \Delta V_{y}^{2}a = \Delta V_{x}^{2} + \Delta V_{y}^{2} \right ) \right ]}$